# TreeSet replacing old values by New values

Tags: java, treeset

I am trying to insert multiple objects in a TreeSet . The problem is one object inserts fine, but when I insert second object and tries to view both objects, I get the second object twice. How can I prevent my old values from getting replaced..

This is my POJO

```
    public Class Question implements Comparable<Question>
    {
     .....
     public int compareTo(Question q) {
    if(vote>q.vote)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

And this is the function which inserts object into the treeSet

```
public void save(String ques, String sessionId, Question question)
{
question.setQuesId(++quesId);                  
question.setQues(ques);
question.setSessionId(sessionId);
question.setVote(0);
setDemo.add(Question);
}
```

Note: "setDemo" is my treeSet object

Any advices are appreciated. 
Thankyou

Comment: Override the `equals()` and `hashCode()`

Comment: @NicholasK can you please be more specific?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java

Comment: When you say you get the second object twice, how do you know they are the same?

Comment: @jbx I print both objects on a datatable and values were same for both objects.

Comment: So like everyone else is telling you... you know that the two objects are equal because you looked at the values... so you have to tell Java to do that too and override the `.equals()` method to compare the values inside your `Question` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your comparator should handle the case in which the votes are equal.

```
public int compareTo(Question q) {
    if(vote>q.vote) {
        return -1;
    } else if (vote<q.vote){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Secondly, make sure you override `equals` properly in `Question`.

If both the `compareTo` method returns 0 and the `equals` returns true, TreeSet will override your value, since it will detect the two values as duplicates. Otherwise, you should not get any replacements.

Although `TreeSet` does not use `hashCode` internally, I would suggest overriding that as well, since you might want to change the implementation from `TreeSet` to `HashSet` in the future.

Comment: My business logic does not require me to check the equal condition as all votes initially be at 0.

Comment: Your business logic might not, but the javadoc for compareTo assumes that you would. Here it is `@return  a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.`. `TreeSet` assumes that you are respecting the contract of `compareTo`, and only in that scenario it will behave as expected.

Comment: If you want to be able to use your TreeSet for just about anything, you need to handle the equality case correctly.